# Remove prefix from custom post type archive page <h1>

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

What is the proper way to remove the taxonomy prefix from the archive page `<title>` AND `<h1>` for custom post types?

I've read a lot of documentation that cites how to remove the (prefix?) from archive and category page titles as well as answers to questions like this. Below is what I'm testing:

```php
function clean_tax_page_title($title) {
    if (is_tax('topics')) {
        $title = single_cat_title('',false);
    }elseif ( is_post_type_archive('topics') ) {
        $title = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', 'clean_tax_page_title');
```

No dice. However, it seems to be working for the the `<title>`. I am a beginner to php and know completely nothing about WordPress core so please spare me. I want the `<h1>` to read "Mindset & Motivation".

[image]

Comment: The site's theme might be interfering: change to a default theme (one of the Twentys), and see if your filter works then. Also, try increasing the filter callback's priority, and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of WordPress 5.5, this is all you need:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', '__return_false' );
```

If this doesn't work then your theme is likely not using `the_archive_title()`, which means that any solution would be specific to your theme's implementation. In that case you will need to ask its author for further assistance.

Comment: This works on all of my other sites with custom themes, and actually so does my initial attempt, but it does not work on Elementor...this is going to be a drag.